# What's the word for the facial expression over an unexpected disappointment?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests, expressions, idioms

If your friend says something sarcastic to you unexpectedly when you are talking about something that makes you exited or your innermost feelings and makes you feel stupid. What's the most widely accepted idiom for your facial expression? Does your **face falls** or **your face clouds over**? Is there a more appropriate word that describes it?

Comment: Cloud over is a very interesting idiom

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*[Chagrined](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/chagrin)*:

> verb
>
> (be chagrined)
>
> Feel distressed or humiliated:
>
> ODO

From *[100 Words for Facial Expressions](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/100-words-for-facial-expressions/)*, by Mark Nichol, on dailywritingtips.com:

> 14. Chagrined: humiliated or disappointed

From *[A Bit of Blue Ribbon](https://books.google.com/books?id=jV0-AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA5&dq=%22chagrined%20face%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=H-wRVdjSGY_igwSIvYPIBw&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22chagrined%20face%22&f=false)*, by Sarah Beaumont Kennedy, in *Outing*, Volume 27, 1896, page 5:

> The girl with the parasol nodded, the marvelous blonde with the
>   *chagrined* face merely turned her head.

From *[The Netherfield Affair](https://books.google.com/books?id=Cav_BgAAQBAJ&pg=PT37&dq=%22chagrined%20face%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Se0RVbu1BoWmNumfgKAG&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22chagrined%20face%22&f=false)*, by Penelope Swan, 2015:

> Elizabeth hid a smile as she saw Miss Bingley's *chagrined* face.

The *[text emoticon](http://www.chatropolis.com/emoticons.html)* for chagrined is half grin; half grimace:

:-/

The emoticon immage:

[image]

Comment: +1 for the text emoji (answer's not half-bad, either).

Comment: @scotM, excellent word...

Answer (score 16):

Possibly "doleful" would be appropriate,

> **doleful** *adjective*: expressing sorrow; mournful. "a *doleful* look"
>
> **synonyms**: mournful, woeful, sorrowful, sad, unhappy, depressed, gloomy, morose, melancholy, miserable, forlorn, wretched, woebegone, despondent, dejected, disconsolate, downcast, crestfallen, downhearted. See, Google [doleful](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=doleful+definition&gws_rd=ssl)

Or perhaps, "crestfallen",

> **crestfallen** *adjective*: sad and disappointed. "he came back empty-handed and *crestfallen*"
>
> **synonyms**: downhearted, downcast, despondent, disappointed. See, Google [crestfallen](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=hss&oq=crestfallen&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=crestfallen+definition&gs_l=hp..4.41l386.0.0.12.625138...........0.iGXpv7NWNgE&gws_rd=ssl)

[image]

**Richard Sherman following Butler's SB interception**

Comment: I saw Richard Sherman's crest fall live: That is a perfect context for *unexpected disappointment*!

Answer (score 4):

There is no word for such a facial expression, except, perhaps, a grimace.

The feeling is `dismay` or `consternation`.

Comment: *Grimace* is one, which could also be used as a verb, e.g. *she grimaced*.But there are others, such as *her face fell*, *she scowled*, *she glowered*, *she winced* , *her face contorted with disappointment* etc.

Answer (score 4):

I think "fall" would work but adding "in disappointment" would make it clearer:

> [His face fell in disappointment.](https://books.google.com/books?id=YKpYAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=%22face%20fell%20in%20disappointment%22&source=bl&ots=wU90guwXf4&sig=cE5Y5WlQ1PeEj-wfF3i22KqwVEo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nfARVceSGJHyoATeuILICA&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22face%20fell%20in%20disappointment%22&f=false)

The link also has some other options for both disappointment (FC122) and embarrassment (FC121, right above).

Answer (score 2):

The answers to this question are very interesting... They all assume that the disappointed party is in a position to display genuine emotion. I have found that the normal response in this situation, if there are others present, is the (often pathetic) *forced smile*. (Think of the expressions of the losing nominees, when the Oscar winner is announced.)

Answer (score 1):

The best answer is grimace

noun
1.
a facial expression, often ugly or contorted, that indicates disapproval, pain, etc.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/grimace

[image: Grimace]

Comment: -1 for copying my answer

Comment: @EmmaDash, + for grimace

Comment: Sorry Emma at the time I posted it I didn't see your response, which is strange because I double checked to make sure.  I'll give you a +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

A downcast expression for a dispirited or resigned feeling?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps *[deflated](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deflated)*

> to reduce in size, importance, or effectiveness *deflate his ego with cutting remarks*

*Merriam-Webster*

Or *[crushed](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/crushed)*

> to defeat or humiliate utterly, as in argument or by a cruel remark

*Collins*

[but I still like @Little Eva's *crestfallen*]

Answer (score 0):

[*"His **face cringed**"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22face%20cringed%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22His%20face%20cringed%22) should be a good candidate, as show the many examples linked from Google Books. That would be after a painfully felt disappointment.

Answer (score 0):

I like the colloquial term *[gobsmacked](https://books.google.com/books?id=LHToAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT26&dq=%22gobsmacked%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DOYSVbXEDIHlggSlioSYBQ&ved=0CDEQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22gobsmacked%22&f=false)*.

> From *That's Not English: Britishisms, Americanisms, and What Our
>   English Says About Us*, by Erin Moore:
>
> Every so often, a word comes along that means just what it sounds
>   like. It may not be onomatopoetic, but even if you've never heard it
>   before, you instantly get the idea. Gobsmacked is such a word. It
>   means, figuratively, to be flabbergasted, amazed, or astounded. 
>   Literally, it means to be smacked in the mouth, as in the song
>   “Gobsmacked” by Chumbawamba (“Outside the pub / Smack you in the gob
>   /...

Comment: Gobsmacked doesn't mean that you were unexpectedly disappointed, does it? It means that you were shocked.